# Authentication required on raspberry pi web server

Tags: authentication, webserver, raspberry-pi, mongoose-web-server

I'm trying to send some JSON data to a webpage via mongoose on my Raspberry Pi. I'm sending the data to port 8080 on the pi itself, but when I navigate my browser to localhost:8080, it asks for authentication. What is my authentication supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't set explicitly `global_auth_file` and `auth_domain` options, authentication is based on .htpasswd in the path you are trying to access.

You can disable authentication globally compiling mongoose with 
`-DMONGOOSE_NO_AUTH`.

Comment: Compiling with -DMONGOOSE_NO_AUTH looks to have worked, thank you!